# Android Icon keeps changing from what I set it to or disappearing entirely from the quick-launch bar at the bottom

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, user-interface, sprint

I have a Galaxy S3 on Sprint, and the quick-launch icons at the bottom of the screen keep messing up.

I have 5 quick-launch icons there, but sometimes one of them either gets removed so only 4 show up, or it duplicates itself and overwrites another one. This leave 5 icons, two of which are the same thing. The icon I've noticed do this the most is `ColorNote`, but others will do it too.

1) What can I do to track down the cause of this anomaly?

2) How do I make it stop?

Anything you can do to point me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this using the default launcher, or a custom (3rd party) launcher installed from Google Play?

Comment: @geffchang This is using the latest version of the native one that shipped with the Galaxy S3. I think it's Samsung's addition to Android, but not sure.